# Is it possible to unit test Net::SMTP email sent with ruby?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, email, smtp

Is it possible to unit test Net::SMTP email sent with ruby?

Some kind of mocking maybe?

Comment: @NeilSlater would you guys mind reopening this one given the edits?

Comment: Why in the world is this off-topic?